# PowerDNS : Respond differently based on Client IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-zone, powerdns, recursive

Currently I'm using Bind9 for my DNS server.

It was set-up in such a way that the server respond differently depending on which IP the request came from. I'm using Bind's View to achieve this.

The conf file is something similar to this :

```
acl trusted { 192.168.7.0/24; localhost; };
acl guest   { 192.168.8.0/24; };

view trusted {
    match-clients { trusted; };

    allow-recursion { any; };

    zone "myzone.example" {
        type master;
        file "db.myzone.example";
    };
    zone "7.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "db.192.168.7";
    };
};

view guest {
    match-clients { guest; };

    allow-recursion { any; };
};
```

**My question is :**

1. Is it possible to do the same with PowerDNS?
2. If yes, What is the easiest way to have it implemented?

Comment: The dup says, either the [GeoIP backend](https://doc.powerdns.com/md/authoritative/backend-geoip/)  or write something in Lua

Comment: Touché. This is a duplicate. I just discovered that the right term for this is Split Horizon.